# ASP.NET app with Sharepoint integration

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

We have ASP.NET business Application which we would like to integrate with Sharepoint. ASP.NET Application have lot of document and search as part of the system. I am putting togeather a Design document. If any one have any tech design template with the topics we need to cover for Sharepoint and ASP.NET integration in prespective of upload documents and search for documents?

Answer (score 0):

For uploading document is same like a file upload in the asp.net only you have to upload in the library in the sharepoint. For search you have to give specific files or restrictions top the users.